# Arquillian: Create a WebArchive from an existing war using ShrinkWrap

Tags: jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am trying to deploy an existing war from another maven project in Arquillian.
I have resolved the war and have it copied to the target directory of my Arquillian project.

I *try* to create it below:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {

    return (WebArchive) ShrinkWrap.create(ZipImporter.class, "MyWarToTest.war").importFrom(
            new File("target/MyWarToTest.war"));

}
```

However, I am getting a class cast exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl cannot be
>   cast to org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive

I am guessing that I should be trying to create the war a different way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer.
I needed to add the .as(WebArchive.class) to the end of the call.
It needs to look like this:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {

    return ShrinkWrap.create(ZipImporter.class, "payloadPlan.war").importFrom(new File("target/payloadPlan.war"))
            .as(WebArchive.class);

}
```

I found the answer here:
http://zezutom.blogspot.com/2012/08/going-mobile-with-arquillian.html

Answer (score 14):

Adding my 2 cents. Even more quick (and with the same result) is the following method:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, new File("target/payloadPlan.war"));
}
```